# How to cuztomize each element of the radio boxes of the foreign key, to add id or classes

Tags: php, symfony

I am new on Symfony, i want to customize each element of the generated radio boxes of the foreign key, i want add some id and class for each element, i can customize the full box but his elements i don't know how !!

```
class NiveauType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('niveau')
                ->add('cycle', EntityType::class, array(
                    "class" => "AdminBundle\Entity\Cycle",
                    "choice_label" => "cycle",
                    "expanded" => true, 
                    "multiple" => false,
                    "attr" => ['class' => 'radioboxes_cycle'] 
                ));
;
    }
```

i can reach his elements by using css, but if there any options to customize them from the FormType or By using twig to add ids to each box

```
<style>
    .radioboxes_cycle{
        font-size:16px; 
        display:inline-flex
    }

    .radioboxes_cycle div{
        margin:10px;
    }


</style>
<div class="modal fade" id="ajouter_niveau" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    {{ form_start(formNiveau, { 'method' : 'post', 'action': path('admin_niveau_new') }) }}
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter un niveau</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group custom-mt-form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Cycle<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                </div>

                {{ form_widget(formNiveau.cycle, {'attr': {'class':'radiobox_cycle'}}) }}

                <div class="form-group custom-mt-form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(formNiveau.niveau) }}
                    <label class="control-label">Niveau<span class="text-danger">*</span></label><i class="bar"></i>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" type="submit">Ajouter</button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(formNiveau) }}
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest to create a new widget, that overwrites the default widget. There you can do what ever you want and will have access to the values of each entity as well as ex. the `attr` array. I'd suggest reading about it here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html and here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html

Comment: thank you, i think this part https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#selectedchoice-selected-value can help

Comment: the probleme is : i want to use modals in my plateforme and so as to avoid using render(controller) functions in the twig due to performances problemes, i want use just javascript to get data into model to make update and delete actions, i can get text type element , but for select box or radio i can't

Comment: radiobuttons and checkboxes move their widgets into the label somehow. modifying form rendering on them (as well as ChoiceType/EntityType items) is notoriously annoying and inconvenient. So good luck. however. you can usually go over `formNiveau.cycle.children` to render/modify each single item. (that is `{% for child in formNiveau.cycle.children %} ... {% endfor %}`) also have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr (it's allowed to be a function!)

Comment: yes , i used this method , thank you

Comment: <div class="radiobox_cycle">
                        {% for key, item in edit_formNiveau.cycle %}
                            <div>
                                
                                <input 
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="cycle_{{key}}"
                                >
                                <label for="{{item.vars.id}}">{{item.vars.label}}</label>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>

Comment: so ... you problem is solved?

Comment: yes, Jakumi , Thank you